# excel merge separate columns into rows

Tags: excel

I have this data in excel
I have a spreadsheet with data like this:

```
Username     GroupName      Output
jsmith       1234           jsmith1234
mdean        2345           jsmith2345
kjack        3456           jsmith3456
             4567           jsmith4567
                            mdean1234
                            mdean2345
                            mdean3456
                            mdean4567
                            kjack1234
                            kjack2345
                            kjack3456
                            kjack4567
```

I want to know if there is a function to create the output based on this set of data. The Username could be more than GroupName or vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=IF(ROW()-ROW($C$2)+1>COUNTA(A2:A)*COUNTA(B2:B),"",INDEX(A2:A,INT((ROW()-ROW($C$2))/COUNTA(B2:B)+1))&INDEX(B2:B,MOD(ROW()-ROW($C$2),COUNTA(B2:B))+1))
```

Pulled from: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/654871-how-generate-all-possible-combinations-two-lists-without-macro.html

Comment: This will include the title row in the output.  Can you modify it to not include the title row?

Comment: `A2:A` is not a proper reference in excel. It works in Google sheets but not excel.